# Call programmatically on selection in Android App

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing a Android app where I want to show the travels contact numbers. Here is the code:

AppActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(AppActivity.this, App2Activity.class);
                i.putExtra("name1","Travels1");
                i.putExtra("number1","7843564358");
                i.putExtra("name2","Travels2");
                i.putExtra("number2","7664764358");
                i.putExtra("name3","Travels3");
                i.putExtra("number3","8804764358");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

App2Activity.java:

```
package com.example.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {
    TextView textView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        final Button btnOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
        final Button btnTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
        final Button btnThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnThree);

        String name1=getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
        String number1=getIntent().getStringExtra("btnOne");
        String name2=getIntent().getStringExtra("name2");
        String number2=getIntent().getStringExtra("btnTwo");
        String name3=getIntent().getStringExtra("name3");
        String number3=getIntent().getStringExtra("btnThree");

        btnOne.setText(number1);
        btnTwo.setText(number2);
        btnThree.setText(number3);

        //textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //textView.setText(name1 + "-" + number1 + " " + name2 + "-" + number2 + " " + name3 + "-" + number3);

        // set button texts from intent data here with getIntent()

        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnOne.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnTwo.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });

        btnThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnThree.getText()));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Travels and Holidays" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/btnThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Travels and Holidays Details</string>

</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mkyong.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".AppActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".App2Activity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat says:

```
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377): Process: com.example.android, PID: 29377
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.App2Activity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at com.example.android.App2Activity.onCreate(App2Activity.java:21)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
05-20 13:49:08.773: E/AndroidRuntime(29377):    ... 10 more
05-20 13:49:10.490: I/Process(29377): Sending signal. PID: 29377 SIG: 9
```

When I click on "Travels and Holidays" button, it directly goes to call option and number to call is `784356435876647643588804764358`.

What I want is: When clicked on "Travels and Holidays" button, it should show:

```
Travels1-7843564358   Call symbol
Travels2-7664764358   Call symbol
Travels3-8804764358   Call symbol
```

And when I click on call of any travels, that should redirect to the call of that number.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problems**

You are directly redirected to the dialer since the call-intent is started in onCreate of your second Activity.

The reason for this long number is the fact that one textview stores all the phone numbers. And in the call intent you pass the complete textview.

**Solution**

In order to prevent this, you should add 3 buttons (where one button stores one phone number) to your second activity's layout file and start the intent in the button click listener passing the telephone number stored in the button (the buttons text)

After adding three new Buttons to the layout-file (used by your second activity) modify the onCreate method to something like that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    // set button texts from intent data here with getIntent()

    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnOne.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnTwo.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    btnThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnThree.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** added full code

Ok, so I coded the app on my PC, here is the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name1","Travels1");
            i.putExtra("number1","7843564358");
            i.putExtra("name2","Travels2");
            i.putExtra("number2","7664764358");
            i.putExtra("name3","Travels3");
            i.putExtra("number3","8804764358");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });   
}
```

}

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Travels and Holidays" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

Button btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOne);
    btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTwo);
    btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnThree);

    // you dont need the names here, but maybe later
    String name1=getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
    String name2=getIntent().getStringExtra("name2");
    String name3=getIntent().getStringExtra("name3");

    String number1=getIntent().getStringExtra("number1");
    String number2=getIntent().getStringExtra("number2");
    String number3=getIntent().getStringExtra("number3");

    btnOne.setText(number1);
    btnTwo.setText(number2);
    btnThree.setText(number3);

    btnOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnOne.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnTwo.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });

    btnThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+btnThree.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnTwo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnThree"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

FYI: The reason why you received the cast-exception was because your three views in the activity_second.xml where TextViews and you casted it as Buttons.

I hope it helps you now!

Comment: This should be in App2Activity or AppActivity?

Comment: I see this should be in App2Activity. I am still not getting what exactly my code should be from your example.

Comment: Yes it should be in App2Activity (thats what I meant by "second activity"). The code is nearly working now. Just replace the two lines "textview = (TextView)findById(..)" and "textView.setText(...)" with three lines that set the telephone number as buttons text: `btnOne.setText(number1);` and the same with the other two buttons. If its working you can then think about how to add the icon

Comment: btnOne = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnTwo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnThree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3); - These 3 lines, i need to create a id for btnOne, btnTwo, btnThree in R.java. But I am not able to do that? R.java modifies to the regenerated version again

Comment: Yes you should add them in your main2 layout. (=drag 3 buttons in layout) The IDs are generated.

Comment: I have edited AppActivity.java, App2Activity.java and main2.xml. But when I run the app, I get the error, Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I mean the app runs. When click on the button "Travels and Holidays", it shows the error message "Unfortunately, Travels and Holidays Details has stopped" and automatically the apps closes. "Travels and Holidays Details" is the app name

Comment: Ok. And what does LogCat say?

Comment: I have put the LogCat in the question

Comment: I am getting Problems in these lines:       
String name1=getIntent().getStringExtra("name1");
String name2=getIntent().getStringExtra("name2");
String name3=getIntent().getStringExtra("name3");
"The value of the local variable name1 is not used"
"The value of the local variable name2 is not used"
"The value of the local variable name3 is not used"

Comment: Ok you can ignore them - these are just warnings. The main problem why the app crashes is `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button`. Solution: Pay attention to the type of view in the layout-file and be sure that you cast views to buttons only when they are buttons, respectively only cast TextViews to TextViews.

Comment: So can you please tell whats the change I need to do? Because I dont see anything wrong in my code because I am a beginner in this field

Comment: Ok, added the complete code (2 activities + 2 layout files) to my answer. (You should have changed the TextViews to Buttons in the second layout file, but you can see it in the full code) Hope it helps you now!

Comment: Wow...Thanks a lot. I have some UI issues still. I will play and sort that out. I got what I wanted finally. I think I need to learn more on this.

Answer (score 0):

How about this!!

Show a `AlertDialog` or a `PopupWindow` (find tutorial [here](http://mrbool.com/how-to-implement-popup-window-in-android/28285)) having a `ListView` with items you want to display. You don't need to start any new `Acitivity` passing your values as `Extras`. Instead, you create a POJO, say `Contact` such as:

```
public class Contact {

    String name;
    String phone;

    public Contact(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name + "-" + this.phone;
    }
}
```

Next, populate your data into say, `final ArrayList<Contact> list = new ArrayList<Contact>();`

like `list.add(new Contact(name1, number1));`

I am using `AlertDialog` instance, but you can use `PopupWindow` and in your `AppActivity`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(App2Activity.this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    LayoutInflater inflater = App2Activity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_list, null);
    alertDialog.setView(view);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listPhone);
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(App2Activity.this, R.layout.alert_list_item, R.id.phoneItem,
            list));

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            Object obj = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            if (obj instanceof Contact) {
                Contact contact = (Contact) obj;
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contact.phone));
                startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

});

Design your `R.layout.alert_list`, with a `ListView`. Design your `R.layout.alert_list_item` with, say, a `TextView` and `ImageView` horizontally aligned, where `ImageView` have phone icon (download any phone icon, may be from [here](http://www.iconsdb.com/))

And you are all set!

Comment: I am still not getting what exactly my code should be from your example.

Comment: which part you didn't get hold of?

Comment: Actually the variables what you wrote is different and what I wrote in my code is different. So I am confused where exactly I should place your code in my code

Comment: Only differences I can see is the introduction of (1) **Contact** class, that you can create a separate java file itself. Its construct accepts, name and phone number pair. (2) **AlertDialog** inside `onClick` of your `button`. It has `R.layout.alert_list` which you need to create a new file with a `ListView` as I already mentioned above.

what else you have problem with?